# Potential for missed version in Subversion (research setting)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisesvn

My first question here and I have not seen it addressed elsewhere. I work in a research institute so we'd like to be able to say which code version produced a particular set of results. My question is whether my analysis is correct as shown in the illustration below (Note that the version node id's are for illustration purposes only and do not correspond to actual version id's in SVN, Git, or Hg. Version numbers with letters represent uncommitted code state in SVN, whole number version id's represent committed state in SVN, all version IDs in Git/Hg box represent committed code state):

[image: Disadvantage of using SVN for research projects?]

Example scenario:

- Suppose there are two working copies "A" and "B" that start from revision 1.
- "A" revises the default values in function `foo()`, generates results, and checks-in the version (repo ver2).
- "B" does not revise `foo()` but some other part of the code, uses the old default values to generate results, and attempts to check-in the as-used version 1b.  It fails because an update is needed, but in the process of merging version 2 and 1b, SVN will lose the fact that version 1b used different default values in `foo()`. This is not detected as a conflict since "A" and "B" did not change the same part of the code. Version 3 is not identical to Version 1b, so replicability is not guaranteed.

I cannot simulate this scenario in my local drive using TortoiseSVN (I cannot create working copies because of SVN Checkout error — "Unable to open an ra_local session to URL"). I do know for a fact that both Git and Hg will handle the situation properly and show version 1b in the history if it was committed and if the rebase feature was not used. (I believe rebase is essentially the normal behavior in SVN when no branches are involved.)

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: Another solution worth mentioning is to share the SVN working copy in a network drive. If anyone knows if this would create a user conflict, such as when SVN requires the user who checked out the working coy to check it in, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please don't share working copies (of any form, SVN, Git, Hg, ...) over a network drive. Letting multiple users access the same working copy is never recommended. The tools might handle it, but it's an error-prone way: imagine I run `hg diff`, am happy with the changes and then run `hg commit`. If we're unlucky, you've made a change between my two command and so I'll commit something I didn't intend!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm just trying to cover most, if not all, of the relevant scenarios. Which one is more error prone - sharing a working copy or having a race condition with multiple working copies? We've been operating in the former mode for a long time now and it has worked more or less. We're only starting to implement version control more strictly, and unfortunately my points about the disadvantages of centralized version control is mostly being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct in principle, even though I would object to the "version 1b" naming. Version 1b does never exist in the SVN realm, because 1b is the state of a working directory before committing.

Your workflow has a fundamental problem: When you want reliable identification of results, you'll *first* have to acquire an identifier and *then* produce results. Check-in, then generate. If this gives reliability problems, check-in to a branch, generate results and then merge. The branch-and-merge approach is similar to the way distributed VCS software like git or hg works, where the local repositories are implicit branches and the push is an implicit merge.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that version 1b (also 1a) naming is misleading. I also agree with the point about acquiring an identifier first, then generate results. It's just that if a researcher forgets to do that first after results have already been generated, we should just be careful to note that checking-in might potentially compromise replicability. Also, both Git and Hg would seem to be less error-prone because the default behavior is to show a divergence from trunk even if no branches were explicitly created beforehand.

Comment: @Edgar: Checking in is never the problem - updating is. It's just that SVN check-ins need to be done on a current version of trunk, so the researcher runs an update, so the results are changed. So you can either train your researchers to re-run computations after every update, you can use a build control software like `make`, or you can use a DVCS like git to remove the update-before-commit need.

Comment: You're right again, my terminology is quite confused. If someone could check-in without needing to do an update, then the version used to generate results is tracked. I have actually recommended using Mercurial and Git just to not even have to worry about this situation, regardless of how infrequently we run into this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that Subversion has this problem. Infact, it's **even worse** than you think. Subversion operates on a per-file basis when it determines if your working copy is out of date. So you can end up with

- A revises default values in `foo()`, and re-runs the experiment. Let's say the change only affect the `results/output-0001.dat`.
- A commits this as SVN revision 2.
- B revises another part of the code and generates new results. Since B doesn't have the change from A, only `results/output-1000.dat` is changed by the rerun.
- B commits this as SVN revision 3.

B could commit **without updating** first since the changes he made did not intersect with the changes made by A. Further more, SVN revision 3 does not correspond to the working copy on either A's or B's machine! If professor C comes along and makes a checkout of SVN revision 3, then he sees:

- `results/output-0001.dat` with the results from A, and
- `results/output-1000.dat` with the results from B.

This is highly inconsistent.

The underlying concept that allows this is [mixed-revision working copies](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs). Subversion allows you to have files in *different revisions* in your working copy. When you create revision 2 with a change to `foo.c`, then that file is marked as being in revision 2. The other files in the working copy remain in revision 1. This allows you to selectively update part of your working copy back to an old revision for debugging purposes, and it allows you to commit files without updating as long as no-one else has touched the file.

Tools like Mercurial and Git will prevent you from doing this since they model the history as a DAG (directed acyclic graph). Each change becomes a new node in the graph and you must made an **explicit** merge commit to combine two changesets. In the scenario above, B would try to push his change and Mercurial would abort. He then does

```
$ hg pull
$ hg merge # he now has both his own and A's changes to the code
$ run-experiment
$ hg commit -m "Merge with new results"
```

All three versions of the results are now stored in the history.

Comment: That is weird that an update is not required in order to commit, I had initially assumed that all working copy files would be re-verified by SVN if the checked revision number does not match the repository's current revision number. The situation is indeed worse than I thought. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've expanded the answer with a bit about these mixed-revision working copies. Please remember to upvote the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Will do once I get 15 reputation. I'm starting to see that many things that I don't like about SVN is not so much due to it being centralized, but due to its emphasis on per-file tracking. For research work, it does seem that the DAG-model would be more reliable.